# Bot upload picture to the channel that the command was executed

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Yes, I've read [this](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-original-message) multiple times. I'm new to Python and Discord bot programming, and I can't figure this out. The command is n!cat (n! is the prefix) and it's just supposed to send a random picture of a cat on the channel that the command was executed. This seems pretty simple, but I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def cat():
    cat_pic = random.randint(1,3)
    if cat_pic == 1:
        await client.send_file(channel, "cat1.jpg")
    elif cat_pic == 2:
        await client.send_file(channel, "cat2.jpg")
    elif cat_pic == 3:
        await client.send_file(channel, "cat3.jpg")
```

As you can see I have not defined `channel` because I don't know how to target the channel where the command was executed. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def cat(ctx):
    cat_pic = random.randint(1,3)
    if cat_pic == 1:
        await client.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "cat1.jpg")
    elif cat_pic == 2:
        await client.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "cat2.jpg")
    elif cat_pic == 3:
        await client.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "cat3.jpg")
```

pass_context in the decorator passes the "context" of the message, which is `ctx` in the parameter. You can use that to send it to the channel.